# XLib: Windows Manager not Sending Client Message after Calling XSetWMProtocols

Tags: c++, xlib

There are many examples on how to handle the closing of a window using XLib, which can be found on the internet:

- http://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/60466-xwindows-close-window-event.html
- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X_Window_Programming/XLib
- https://john.nachtimwald.com/2009/11/01/x11-intercept-window-close-event/

There are several more. That said I have tried to implement them in code, as seen below. However when I click on X in the corner of my window I get no event sent to my message loop. Is this because `XChcekWindowEvent` ignores or does not process Client Messages? If this is not the case what are some other things I should be looking for to get messages from XLib set using `SetWMProtocols`?

```
m_impl->m_delete_window = XInternAtom(display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", False);
if (!XSetWMProtocols(display, window, &m_impl->m_delete_window, 1)) {
  std::cout << "Set Window Protocols Failed" << std::endl;
}

...

while (!terminate) {
  while (::XCheckWindowEvent(display, window, events::mask, &x_event)) {
    if (x_event.type == ClientMessage) {
      std::cout << "Client Message" << std::endl;   
      if ((Atom)x_event.xclient.data.l[0] == m_impl->m_delete_window) {
        terminate = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XCheckWindowEvent() will not return ClientMessage. It returns none of the non maskable ones. Work around:

```
while (XPending(display))
{
    XNextEvent(display, &event);
```

But could create extra work to filter event by window.
BR Pekka

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent using `XNextEvent` (which is not applied in real-time event loops), you may use the following code based on `XCheckTypedWindowEvent`:

```
// Globals

Atom wm_protocols;
Atom wm_delete_window;

// Functions

void PreventClose(Display* disp, Window& win)
{
  wm_protocols = XInternAtom(disp, "WM_PROTOCOLS", false);
  wm_delete_window = XInternAtom(disp, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", false);
  XSetWMProtocols(disp, win, &wm_delete_window, 1);
}

bool IsClosed(Display* disp, Window& win)
{
  XEvent e;
  if (XCheckTypedWindowEvent(disp, win, ClientMessage, &e))
    if (e.xclient.message_type == wm_protocols &&
        e.xclient.data.l[0]    == wm_delete_window_)
      return true;
  return false;
}

// Usage

int main()
{
   ...
   PreventClose(disp, win);
   do {
     if (IsClosed(disp, win))
       // break, some actions, etc...
     ...
   } while(true);
   return 0;
}
```

For more info see `man 3 XCheckTypedWindowEvent`